# Модификаторы \А  \X

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

/X, (?X) - extra
Запретить экранировать буквы без специального назначения.

/A - anchored
Заякорить выражение к началу текста. Аналогично использованию якоря \A в самом начале выражения.

Мне не понятно что это за модификаторы?

Просьба подкрепить примером.

Answer (score 2):

Модификатор `A` подобен тому, как если бы вы шаблон начали писать с `^`. Т.е. следующие строки равнозначны:

```
echo preg_replace('#df#A', 'TEST', 'dfghjk') . "\n";
echo preg_replace('#^df#', 'TEST', 'dfghjk') . "\n";
```

А `X` запрещает использование в квадратных скобках конструкций `'\{буква}`, которые не определены в PCRE. Т.е., например, `\d` - можно использовать, а `\C` - нет. Без модификатора последний пример будет просто использовать символ `'C'`.

[Примеры](http://ideone.com/19bUSD)

Comment: Эти два выражения не равносильны. Якорем будет конец предыдущего совпадения, а не начало строки:  
http://ideone.com/N05qy .  
Про **Х** тоже не совсем верно. Не обязательно экранированный символ должен быть внутри квадратных скобок.

Comment: Что-то не открывается идеон. Запустите такой код:  

    preg_match_all("/a/A", "aaaaaa", $res1);
    preg_match_all("/^a/", "aaaaaa", $res2);
    preg_match_all("/a/A", "aaabaaa", $res3);

И посмотрите содержимое результатов.

Comment: Пожалуй, ваше уточнение существенно

http://ideone.com/vD7kfb